# Wrong character reading QRCode with iPhone 15

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, qr-code

I made a basic demo app in Swift to scan QRcodes, but when I use an iPhone 15, it adds an extra character that isn't on the QRcode. All other iPhone models read it correctly. They're all running iOS 17.1.1. Is anyone facing this problem? The code is very simple and it's the demo provide by Apple.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }

        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        }

        // Set up the metadata output
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            print(stringValue)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the offending QR code, plus what you expect to get and actually get as its contents?

Comment: sorry, it contains classified information. But I found a way to fix it by setting the preset to  photo quality.

`captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo`

thanks :)

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question with what you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the preset to the max resolution available solves my problem.

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(.photo) {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
}
```